# Pandas : select row where column A does not begin with column B

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to select all those rows in a data frame where column A (string) does not begin with column B(string) .I used

```
df[not df['A'].str.startswith(df['B']) ]
```

but it is showing not a boolean value.

eg :

```
      A       B


 1. abcdef  abc
 2. ab      cd
 3. ef      g
```

Then the required output is:

eg :

```
     A       B

 1. ab       cd
 2. ef       g
```

Please help.

Comment: Please share sample input with expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
In [250]: data={'A': ['abcdef', 'ab', 'ed'], 
     ...:         'B': ['abc', 'cd','g']} 
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame(data)

In [251]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[251]: 
        A    B
0  abcdef  abc
1      ab   cd
2      ed    g

In [248]: df[~df.A.str.contains('|'.join(df.B))]                                                                                                                                                            
Out[248]: 
    A   B
1  ab  cd
2  ed   g
```

Comment: It is showing the following error : sequence item 170085: expected str instance, float found.

Comment: Looks like your df has float values. Can you please share your df?

Comment: Ok but the error is not fixed yet : nothing to repeat at position 4749344

Comment: better would be if you could give a try statement for the same.

Comment: Would be better if you could share a sample if your df which is causing issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
data={'A': ['abcdef', 'ab', 'ed'],
        'B': ['abc', 'cd','g']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df[df.apply(lambda x: x.B not in x.A, axis=1)]
```

It gives you the exact result you want.